# Terraform: Error creating ECR Repository, RepositoryAlreadyExistsException for AWS Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, terraform, amazon-ecr

I am trying to create two lambdas that are deployed as docker images to two separate ECR repositories. Here is my folder structure:

```
- main.tf
- variables.tf 
- lambda_functions/
  - main.tf
  - ...
- ecr_repository/
  - main.tf
  - ...
```

This is `ecr_repository/main.tf`:

```
resource "aws_ecr_repository" "converter_repo" {
  name = "cs-lambda-converter-repo-${var.environment}"
  force_delete = true
}

resource "aws_ecr_repository" "uploader_repo" {
  name = "cs-lambda-uploader-repo-${var.environment}"
  force_delete = true
}

output "converter_repo_url" {
  value = aws_ecr_repository.converter_repo.repository_url
}

output "uploader_repo_url" {
  value = aws_ecr_repository.uploader_repo.repository_url
}

output "converter_repo_name" {
  value = aws_ecr_repository.converter_repo.name
}

output "uploader_repo_name" {
  value = aws_ecr_repository.uploader_repo.name
}
```

And my `lambda_functions/main.tf`

```
module "ecr_repository" {
  source      = "../ecr_repository"
  environment = var.environment
}

locals {
  uploader_image_tag        = "latest"
  converter_image_tag       = "latest"
}

data "aws_ecr_image" "uploader_lambda_image" {
  depends_on = [
    null_resource.ecr_uploader_image
  ]
  repository_name = module.ecr_repository.uploader_repo_name
  image_tag       = local.uploader_image_tag
}

data "aws_ecr_image" "converter_lambda_image" {
  depends_on = [
    null_resource.ecr_converter_image
  ]
  repository_name =  module.ecr_repository.converter_repo_name
  image_tag       =  local.converter_image_tag
}

resource "null_resource" "ecr_uploader_image" {

  triggers = {
    python_file = md5(file("${var.lambda_uploader_path}/lambda_function.py"))
    docker_file = md5(file("${var.lambda_uploader_path}/Dockerfile"))
  }
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command     = <<EOF
      rm ~/.docker/config.json 2> /dev/null
      aws ecr get-login-password --region ${var.region} | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin ${data.aws_caller_identity.current.account_id}.dkr.ecr.${var.region}.amazonaws.com
      docker buildx build --platform linux/amd64 -t ${module.ecr_repository.uploader_repo_url}:${local.uploader_image_tag} .
      docker push ${module.ecr_repository.uploader_repo_url}:${local.uploader_image_tag}
    EOF
    interpreter = ["bash", "-c"]
    working_dir = var.lambda_uploader_path
  }
}

resource "null_resource" "ecr_converter_image" {

  triggers = {
    python_file = md5(file("${var.lambda_converter_path}/lambda_function.py"))
    docker_file = md5(file("${var.lambda_converter_path}/Dockerfile"))
  }
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command     = <<EOF
      rm ~/.docker/config.json 2> /dev/null
      aws ecr get-login-password --region ${var.region} | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin ${data.aws_caller_identity.current.account_id}.dkr.ecr.${var.region}.amazonaws.com
      docker buildx build --platform linux/amd64 -t ${module.ecr_repository.converter_repo_url}:${local.converter_image_tag} .
      docker push ${module.ecr_repository.converter_repo_url}:${local.converter_image_tag}
    EOF
    interpreter = ["bash", "-c"]
    working_dir = var.lambda_converter_path
  }
}

resource "aws_lambda_function" "pdf-uploader" {
  depends_on = [
    null_resource.ecr_uploader_image
  ]
  function_name = "capsphere-ocr-uploader-${var.environment}"
  role          = aws_iam_role.lambda-role.arn
  timeout       = 300
  memory_size   = 512
  image_uri     = "${module.ecr_repository.uploader_repo_url}:${local.uploader_image_tag}"
  package_type  = "Image"
}

resource "aws_lambda_function" "pdf-converter" {
  depends_on = [
    null_resource.ecr_converter_image
  ]
  function_name = "capsphere-ocr-converter-${var.environment}"
  role          = aws_iam_role.lambda-role.arn
  timeout       = 300
  memory_size   = 512
  image_uri     = "${module.ecr_repository.converter_repo_url}:${local.converter_image_tag}"
  package_type  = "Image"
}

output "uploader_lambda_name" {
  value = aws_lambda_function.pdf-uploader.function_name
}

output "converter_lambda_name" {
  value = aws_lambda_function.pdf-converter.function_name
}
```

I get these errors about trying to create a new ECR repository:

```
Ôöé Error: creating ECR Repository (cs-lambda-converter-repo-dev): RepositoryAlreadyExistsException: The repository with name 'cs-lambda-converter-repo-dev' already exists in the registry with id 'XXXXX'
Ôöé
Ôöé   with module.lambda_functions.module.ecr_repository.aws_ecr_repository.converter_repo,
Ôöé   on modules\ecr_repository\main.tf line 1, in resource "aws_ecr_repository" "converter_repo":
Ôöé    1: resource "aws_ecr_repository" "converter_repo" {
Ôöé
ÔòÁ
ÔòÀ
Ôöé Error: creating ECR Repository (cs-lambda-uploader-repo-dev): RepositoryAlreadyExistsException: The repository with name 'cs-lambda-uploader-repo-dev' already exists in the registry with id 'XXXXX'
Ôöé
Ôöé   with module.ecr_repository.aws_ecr_repository.uploader_repo,
Ôöé   on modules\ecr_repository\main.tf line 6, in resource "aws_ecr_repository" "uploader_repo":
Ôöé    6: resource "aws_ecr_repository" "uploader_repo" {
```

I'm not sure which bit in my terraform script is trying to recreate the ECR repository. I've tried refactoring and checking for separate terraform states, but none of those seem to work.

Comment: Maybe you created it manually, without using tf?

Comment: @Marcin no, definitely not the case- I made sure all the resources were taken down with `terraform destroy` and also checked the UI.

Comment: Check if for any reason the repository is in the terraform state

Answer (score 0):

I've figured it out, for some reason by removing the import module, the problem goes away. So I take this out:

```
module "ecr_repository" {
  source      = "../ecr_repository"
  environment = var.environment
}
```

I think the terraform code below never actually uses that import.